# Pushing several elements into aggregated list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How I can do correct push into my aggregated list ?

```
db.getCollection('rty').aggregate(
    { $match: {'id': 110451}},
    { $unwind: '$matches'},
    { $match: {'matches.majority.uuid': {'$exists': true}}},
    { $group: {_id: '$id', list: {$push: {'$matches.majority.uuid' , 'matches.majority.confidence'}}}})
```

When I push only `uuid` it's working, but how I can use two fields here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [`$push` on aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/), please try it as below

```
db.getCollection('rty').aggregate(
    { $match: {'id': 110451}},
    { $unwind: '$matches'},
    { $match: {'matches.majority.uuid': {'$exists': true}}},
    { $group: {_id: '$id', list: 
         {$push: 
            {uid: '$matches.majority.uuid' , 
             conf: 'matches.majority.confidence'}}}});
```